# I am getting error "syntax error: unexpected end of file" for below code

Tags: shell, scripting

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
CHECK=`/opt/OV/TNT/adapter/bin/temip_adapter_show | grep "The Adapter is initialized and ready" | wc -l`
if [$CHECK -ne 0]
then
echo "Atni adapter is already running, Please check"
else
/opt/OV/TNT/adapter/bin/temip_adapter -start
fi
mailx -s "NNMi Atni Adapter status" -r srijan.chaudhary@hpe.com <<-EOF
```

Hi Team,

NNMi Atni adapter successfully started

Regards,
NNM Server
EOF

Comment: plese [edit] the question with a proper format. See [formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing last line as :
mailx -s "TeMIP Server has been successfully started" srijan.chaudhary@hpe.com -- -f srijan.chaudhary@hpe.com <<-EOF

and also by clearing all the special characters withing the script.

Answer (score 0):

add spaces after [ and before ] as below; You can try this;

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_22
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
CHECK=`/opt/OV/TNT/adapter/bin/temip_adapter_show | grep "The Adapter is initialized and ready" | wc -l`
if [ $CHECK -ne 0 ]
then
echo "Atni adapter is already running, Please check"
else
/opt/OV/TNT/adapter/bin/temip_adapter -start
fi
echo "NNMi Atni Adapter status" | mailx -s "NNMi Atni Adapter status" srijan.chaudhary@hpe.com
```

Comment: @SrijanChaudhary : you can also change mailx part as above ?

Comment: issue is resolved now, it was due to special characters.